# Thoughts on survival very near to a white dwarf

Tags: planets

I'm piecing together a short graphic story about the last few thousand "people" on a small rocky planet that has partially survived the destruction of it's solar system. I wanted to explore the science facts around this idea.

Could a planetoid in close proximity to the white dwarf receive some kind of energy, or even some kind of light? Enough for these remaining people to at least fight over - which is an aspect of the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact there are arguments that [life could evolve on a planet circling a white dwarf](http://www.centauri-dreams.org/?p=23911).  If this is possible, it certainly is possible to colonize a planet around a white dwarf within the habitable zone (i.e. liquid water exists).  Such a planet may have acquired its water from comets or icy body collisions AFTER the violent formation of the white dwarf.  Of course, it would be dicey... such a planet would have to be very close to the white dwarf and thus would probably be tidally locked (one side facing the white dwarf always).

A typical old white dwarf with luminosity 0.0001 of the sun's luminosity would require that the planet orbit at 0.01 AU to be in the habitable zone.  This could be stable for a very long time (in human terms).